# LSTM Timeseries recursive prediction converge to same value

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, keras, multi-step

I'm working on Timeseries sequence prediction using LSTM. 
My goal is to use window of 25 past values in order to generate a prediction for the next 25 values. I'm doing that recursively:
I use 25 known values to predict the next value. Append that value as know value then shift the 25 values and predict the next one again until i have 25 new generated values (or more)

I'm using "Keras" to implement the RNN
Architecture:

```
regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32)
```

Problem: 
Recursive prediction always converge to the some value no matter what sequence comes before.

For sure this is not what I want, I was expecting that the generated sequence will be different depending on what I have before and I'm wondering if someone have an idea about this behavior and how to avoid it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong ...

[image: exemple1]
[image: exemple2]

I tried different epochs number and didn't help much, actually more epochs made it worse. Changing Batch Size, Number of Units , Number of Layers , and window size didn't help too in avoiding this issue.

I'm using MinMaxScaler for the data.

**Edit:**

scaling new inputs for testing:

```
dataset_test = sc.transform(dataset_test.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Have you rescaled new inputs in the same way as previous ones?

Comment: sure. yes i did

Comment: Can you show how? Another quick fix - try to use `predict_on_batch` instead of `predict`

Comment: I attached my rescaling for test data

Comment: Ok - it seems fine - now try using `predict_on_batch` instead of `predict`.

Comment: Doesn't this require train_on_batch too ? and from keras documentation i don't get what's the difference between predict and predict on_batch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163581/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-user3375448).

Comment: @MarcinMożejko any new thoughts what can be the problem ?